# Executing simple ruby apps on nitrous.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, nitrousio

I am currently doing a tutorial on ruby and am using the Nitrous.io IDE. I was wondering how I can run a simple ruby app in the console. The lines of code in my test.rb are no more than 5 lines. This website says that I should use "load 'file_name.rb'" but that does nothing. And when I try that on my local computer (Windows), I get "cannot load such file" I have the file located within the same dir and it still does not work. Could someone please help. Thank you in advance!
http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/ruby_in_100_minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

To run a ruby file, type in the following command within the terminal (replacing `file-name.rb` with your actual file):

```
ruby file-name.rb
```

If you need to install Ruby on your Nitrous box then you can install this through [Autoparts](http://help.nitrous.io/autoparts) (`parts install ruby2.1`).